# For $0 \leq a,b \leq 1$, why does $a<b$ imply $\frac a{1-a }< \frac b{1-b}$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

For $0 \leq a,b \leq 1$, why does $a<b$ imply $\frac a{1-a }< \frac b{1-b}$?

Do we need to compute derivatives to validate this inequality? Or talk about increasing/decreasing functions?

Comment: You don't *need* to compute a derivative, but it's pretty easy to see that $x/(1 - x)$ is increasing on $(0, 1)$ from the derivative.

Answer (score 3):

$$a<b \\\Rightarrow a-ab<b-ab\\\Rightarrow a(1-b)<b(1-a)\\\Rightarrow\frac{a}{1-a}<\frac{b}{1-b}$$
All calculations are valid because $0\leq a, b \leq 1$

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
a-ab<b-ab.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac 1{\frac x{1-x}} = \frac 1x - 1$.

Clearly $\frac 1a > \frac 1b$. Now subtract $1$ from both sides, take the reciprocal (and flip the inequality).

Answer (score 0):

If $0\le a\lt b\le1$, then the numerators and denominators of $a/(1-a)$ and $b/(1-b)$ are all nonnegative (and all positive if $0\lt a\lt b\lt1$). Now the numerator of $b/(1-b)$ is *greater* than the numerator of $a/(1-a)$, and the denominator of $b/(1-b)$ is *smaller* than the denominator of $a/(1-a)$. Therefore the fraction $b/(1-b)$ is larger than the fraction $a/(1-a)$. If you like,

$${a\over1-a}\lt{a\over1-b}\lt{b\over1-b}$$

or, if you prefer,

$${a\over1-a}\lt{b\over1-a}\lt{b\over1-b}$$

(Note, we are presumably meant to accept $b/(1-b)=\infty$ if $b=1$.)

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the inequality as follows:

\begin{align}&\frac{a}{1-a}<\frac{b}{1-b}\\&\frac{a}{a-1}>\frac{b}{b-1}\\&\frac{a-1+1}{a-1}>\frac{b-1+1}{b-1}\\&1+\frac{1}{a-1}>1+\frac{1}{b-1}\\&\frac{1}{a-1}>\frac{1}{b-1}\end{align}

From $a<b$ it follows that $a-1<b-1<0$ and the inequality is thus satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

If $a \lt b \lt 1$ then $(1 - a) \gt (1-b) \gt 0$. But then (inversion rule)

$\tag 1 0 \lt \frac{1}{1-a} \lt \frac{1}{1-b}$.

Multiplication of non-negative quantities preserves the inequality, so with (1) and

$\tag 2 0 \le a \lt b$

we get

$\tag 3 0 \le \frac{a}{1-a} \lt \frac{b}{1-b}$.